# How to install alien in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, system-installation, alien

I have Ubuntu 14.04, I want to install Alien; I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 unixodbc vim
```

the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
alien is already the newest version.
libaio1 is already the newest version.
unixodbc is already the newest version.
vim is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 403 not upgraded.
```

When I tried: *sudo apt-get install alien*

the result was

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Plz help in installing `alien`.

Comment: there is no problem at all.

Comment: `alien is already the newest version.`

Answer (score 1):

try running the following commands in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

Run following command to change the format of the package.

```
sudo alien filename.rpm
```

i**nstall the** **`.deb`** **package:**

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

the otherway:- install **gdebi**

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

now right click on `.deb` file and open with `gdebi`

Comment: is probleem : dpkg-dev is already the newest version.

Comment: @SalamBoy And how is this a problem?

Comment: if i write the command :  sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential ; the resultat is : E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Answer (score 0):

List the output of alien first. You may want to use `sudo apt reinstall alien`. This has helped me in 80% of my problems.